# ftp error message: Create Directory Operation Failed vs Cannot created a file when that file already exists

Tags: windows, ftp, mkdir

I made an program that works on windows.
It connects to a ftp server, makes directory and uploads files to ftp.

So I made a ftp server to test it.
Whenever I try to make a directory which already exists, 'Cannot created a file when that file already exists' error message appeared.

However, I tried to do the same thing on a customer's site with their own ftp server, and a different error message showed up, 'Create Directory Operation Failed'.
No error was there when I try to make non-duplicate directory.

The biggest problem in here is that for the first case, even with the error message, my program keeps executing.
However, for the second case, when my program meets the error message, it just ends immediately.
I cannot find any difference but those error message for this situation.

Can anybody tell me why are they having different error message?
Thanks..

Comment: Can you please share the script you are using information like the ftp server type and version?

Comment: Actually I am very new with ftp server, I don't know what kind of information should I share and where to find them.. I just made up the server using IIS. and I don't know anything about customer's ftp server. They just gave me the IP address, Username and Password. Can it be because of different type & version of ftp server?

Comment: Yeah, that's most likely the problem.  Please ask them for that information and please post the script you're using.

Comment: Every FTP server behaves (potentially) differently and displays different messages. If you want to make your client reacting right, stick to the [FTP Server return codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes). Those are the same everywhere.